# function executed twice if page is not reloaded

Tags: javascript

```
$(document).on('click', '.imgdel', function() {
    if (!$('.imgstore').hasClass('imgact')) {return false;}
    mdialog('DELETE', 'IMAGE WILL BE DELETED', 'OK', delimg);
});

function mdialog(title, story, btn, fn) {
    $('#dgtitle').text(title);
    $('#dgstory').html(story);
    $('#dgok').text(btn).click(function(){fn()});
    $('#mdialog').show();
}

function delimg() {
    console.log('delimg');
};
```

First click on `dgok` - everything ok.

Reload page - repeat all - everything ok.

Repeating all - **without** reloading the page - console is written `delimg` - **twice!**

Any help?

Comment: When you add the click handler twice, it will also be executed twice.

Comment: Also, as a code style... I'd recommend using full variable / function names (`button` instead of `btn`, `deleteImage` instead of `delimg`, etc), rather than these abbreviations.  You'll thank yourself later....

Comment: It sounds like `#dgok` is ALSO `.imgdel`?  If so, as @str points out, you're adding the click handler multiple times to the same element.

Comment: @cale_b, why is `deleteImage` better than `delimg` ?

Comment: As explained here (and in other places): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5196674/should-i-write-more-descriptive-function-names-or-add-comments and https://medium.com/coding-skills/clean-code-101-meaningful-names-and-functions-bf450456d90c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just disable your previous handlers with jQuery `.off()` function :

```
$('#dgok').text(btn).off('click').click(function(){fn()});
```

Comment: Not sure this will work, as the original binding is to the `document`, not `#dgok`....

Comment: Is there another way to assign a function to a button - without its execution? I need to execute them only by `dgok` click.

Comment: @puerto - you need to share your rendered HTML.  It's pretty much impossible to help you without it, including answering questions like in your comment.

Comment: @cale_b, what about `data-fn="delimg"`? How to call them?

Comment: `$('[data-fn="delimg"]').on('click')`

Comment: @Zenoo, I mean - `<div id='dgok' data-fn='delimg'>OK</div>`. How to execute `delimg` clicking on `dgok`?

Comment: And why this happens only if the page is not reloaded?

Comment: @puerto **Read the comments**.  I've told you at least _twice_ - nobody can help you until you _share your HTML_.  Your question is receiving votes to close _because you don't have the relevant HTML_.